# JVM strings stored in memory

Tags: java, memory, jvm

What is the difference (memory-wise) between

```
private static final String FAILURE_MESSAGE=    "...";

protected String getFailedMsg() {
    return FAILURE_MESSAGE;
}
```

And

```
protected String getFailedMsg() {
    return "...";
}
```

Assuming that the `FAILURE_MESSAGE` is only referenced from the above function.

I mean where and how are the above objects/strings being held in memory in the above cases? 
Is it JVM specific?

Edit: I know that the string is interned in the first approach, but where is it value being stored/held/(interned?) in the second approach before the function is called?

Second edit as an afterthought - what if the strings are replaced with ints or some other class that is not a string?

Comment: You mean to return {START_MESSAGE}? You have returned {FAILURE_MESSAGE}.

Comment: @sans481 - thanks, stupid copy paste mistake...

Comment: It is worth noting that all of you String literals `"..."` will reference the same instance in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytecode generated are the same in both cases:

```
protected java.lang.String getFailedMsg()
    0 ldc 2 (java.lang.String) "..."
    2 areturn
```

so it's purely sugar.

Answer (score 4):

The first example doesn't compile and the second example does.

Performance is usually less important than simplicity and clarity, and you have a good example here of that.  If it did compile, the first example would be as fast as the second.

BTW: It doesn't matter how many times and in how many classes a string literal is used, they will all be [String.intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) so they will all be the same object.

Comment: Sorry about the mix up, it was a copy paste mistake, but the question still holds.

Comment: So you say that the string literal in the second approach is interned and occupies memory in the pool even if the function is never called? When is it interned then? First call of the function or during the class loading or during something else?

Comment: Oh, and what happens if the strings are replaced with ints in my examples?

Comment: a) It's stored in the class's constant pool, so it's interned when the class is loaded. b) The exact same thing, although the constant might just get inlined.

Answer (score 1):

String literals refer to the same `String` object, so there is no difference memory-wise in this case.

Section *3.10.5 String Literals* of the *Java Language Specification 3.0* states:

> A string literal always refers to the same instance (§4.3.1) of class String... [they] are
>   “interned” so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

Answer (score 1):

All String literals will be interned, so it doesn't make any difference (memory-wise, looking at the `String` instance).

The only difference is that in your first case, the class holds one reference pointer to the String instance. The second approach creates the reference on the stack only.

Comment: But where the string value stored **before** it's created on the stack in the second approach?

Comment: @Vic: The value is never created on the stack (only the reference is). All Java objects are created on the heap (well, some modern JVMs create short-lived objects on the heap, but that's not relevant here).

Comment: The second part of your comment "the only difference".. is not right.  In both cases the bytecode created for the method is "LDC <string>" then "areturn".

Answer (score 0):

In both the cases, it creates literal in string pool. After creating String s = "...", if u try to return "..." in any method, both point to one string literal created in string pool.